# Анимированные кнопки border

Tags: css3, css-animation

Как сделать вот такую кнопку в css (без картинок) и чтобы при наведении на неё, с правой стороны border заполнялся до конца?
Я понимаю, что здесь нельзя просить скрипты, но другого выхода уже просто не вижу, 2 часа просидел, так и не смог ни чего сделать...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background: #000;
    font-family: 'segoe ui', sans-serif;
}

.btn{
    margin: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s;
}
.btn:before,
.btn:after,
.btn > span:before,
.btn > span:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
    border: 3px solid #B3B3B3;
    transition: .3s;
}

.btn:before{
    top: 0; left: 0;    
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.btn:after{
    top: 0; right: 0;    
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.btn > span{
    display: block;   
}
.btn > span:before{
    bottom: 0; left: 0;    
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.btn > span:after{
    bottom: 0; right: 0;    
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}
.btn:hover:after{
    height: calc(100% - 15%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
Button text
<span></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы по кругу заполнялось с правой стороны?

Comment: `.btn:hover:before{
    height: calc(100% - 15%);
    width: calc(100% - 15%);
}`

Сделал ещё так, но нижнюю часть не закрывает

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/3sgsun3t/

Comment: @soledar16 по кругу надо чтобы :c

Comment: Всё, разобрался, спасибо огромное ещё раз

`.btn:hover:after{
    height: calc(100% - 15%);
}
.btn:hover > span:after{
    width: calc(100% - 15%);
}

.btn:hover:before{
    width: calc(100% - 15%);
}
.btn:hover > span:before{
    height: calc(100% - 15%);
}
`

Answer (score 1):

В начале презентация, потом описание что происходит:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:0 auto;  
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0) 31%, transparent 31%, transparent 69%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 69%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 100%);
  padding: 10px;  
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;  
  background: #e8e8e8;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fillline {
  background: #0000ff;
  width: 10px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container .inner {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
    from {
      top: -60px;       
    }
    to {
      top: 60px; 
    }
  }

.container:hover .fillline {  
  animation: myAnimation 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"> тут какой-то текст</div>
  <div class="fillline"></div>
</div>
```

(**Заметка**) В хроме работает точно. Для других браузеров посмотреть нужны ли где префиксы (например для `animation-fill-mode` или `animation`)

Суть в чём:

1. Чтоб сделать такой рисунок без картинки придется извратиться и использовать **[repeating-linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient)**. В нем задаем цвета для градиента контейнера. А чтоб не было видно этого градиента, то каждый последующий цвет начинается ровно в конце предыдущего.
   Кстати есть такая штука как **[border-image-repeat](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image-repeat)**, чтоб делать края повторяющейся картинкой
2. Конечно градиент распространяется на весь контейнер, поэтому текст должен располагаться в своем внутреннем контейнере.
3. Т.к. даже с помощью такого градиента нельзя сделать "дырки" по краям, то применяем `.container:after` на всю ширину контейнера, при этом закрашивая правый и левый край под цвет фона (в данном случае он белый).
   Этот блок я специально выделил серым цветом, чтоб его было видно.
4. Т.к. анимацию заполнения края справа без извращений не сделать (как мне показалось), то дополнительно вставим элемент `div.fillline`, который расположим 
   в верхнем правом углу контейнера. Зададим ему `z-index` больше чем у `.container:after`, чтобы перекрыть его. Этот элемент я специально выделил синим цветом, чтоб его было видно.

   **Примечание!** вместо того чтобы делать `.container:after` на всю ширину, можно сделать `.container:after` - с правой границы контейнера, по ширине равной `border`, а также `.container:before` — расположить его с левой стороны контейнера и также сделать шириной как `border`.
5. Собственно сама анимация: сдвигаем `fillline` так, как нам необходимо. **[animation-fill-mode: forwards;](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp)** - оставляет стили на момент завершения движения

Comment: мощно, однако... а закрыть фрагменты border тонюсенькими дивами и когда нужно делать какой-то (например правый) прозрачным? знаю что кропотливая работа, но то что предлагается - полный трэш вообще, просто в отрыве...

Comment: @EugeneBartosh прозрачный див даст что? если цвет границы какого-либо цвета, то прозрачный цвет другого дива его перекроет? бред. Можно расставить по краям два дива и один для анимации перекрытия (итого три), однако получится не меньший бред. Чисто посредством css такой эффект можно получить лишь извращением (на мой взгляд)...... был бы js и border картинкой — вcе делалось бы гораздо проще. Но вас никто не останавливает предложить ответ со своим изящным красивым идеальным решением ))

Comment: ну я предложил с дивами, нормальное решение, фон того дива который перекрывает рамку, совпадает с фоном основного дива, я не знаю что тут может быть непонятно... надо показать всю рамку - див становится прозрачным

Comment: @EugeneBartosh `надо показать` - покажите, никто вас не держит))